# Java Reference pointer

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    class Tree{
        int value;
        Tree[] branches;
    }

    int a[]=new int[]{0,1,2};

    Tree[] objTree=new Tree[a.length+1];        
    for(int j=0;j<objTree.length;j++)
    {
        objTree[j]=new Tree();

        objTree[j].branches=new Tree[5];
        for(int i=0;i<objTree[j].branches.length;i++){
            objTree[j].branches[0]=new Tree();
        }
    }
    objTree[0].value=4;
}
```

objTree[0].value=4; works fine when i use this code.But when i use the below one, it throws an exception

```
for(Tree t:objTree)
{
    t=new Tree();
    t.value=5;
    t.branches=new Tree[5];
    for(int i=0;i<t.branches.length;i++){
        t.branches[0]=new Tree();
    }
}
objTree[0].value=4;
```

objTree[0].value=4 throws an  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException. Can anyone please explain to me what is the reason?

Comment: Pointer is not a term in Java!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan It should be since that's what you have (Ever hear of a `NullPointerException` ?)  ;)

Comment: To the OP: You get that exception for exactly one reason: `objTree[0]` is `null`.

Comment: Sure.  In the lower code, you never define objTree.  In the upper code, you define objTree in the first line of the loop.

Comment: @BrianRoach Agree!  you correct me actually  :) :)

Comment: The term is actually defined in [the language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1): "*The reference values (often just references) are **pointers** to these objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop, you assign a value to `t`, which is just a copy of a`null` value from `objTree`. Changing `t` doesn't change the value of the array element in `objTree` -- once the value is copied into `t`, they are two separate unrelated values. You need to use a traditional `for` loop, something like

```
for(int j=0; j<objTree.length; ++j) {
        Tree t=new Tree();
        t.value=5;
        t.branches=new Tree[5];
        ...
        objTree[j] = t;
}
```

Another answer, now deleted, pointed out that in your other `for` loop -- the inner one -- the line

```
t.branches[0]=new Tree();
```

should be

```
t.branches[i]=new Tree();
```